# Why won't iTunes 12 add movies?

Tags: itunes, video

I'm trying to add a movie file to iTunes 12. I've tried dragging and dropping and "Add to Library" from the iTunes File menu, but neither work. The movie isn't being sent to the "Home Movies" section, either.

Any ideas as to how I can resolve this?

Comment: It doesn't show up in the "Recently Added" playlist either I assume? Which Handbrake preset did you use?

Comment: No, it's not appearing in "Recently Added", either. I'm using the Handbrake preset "iPhone and iPod touch". When I click "Add to Library" and then select the file I want to add, nothing happens.

Comment: Importing audio tracks is possible still? Or reset warnings (Preferences->Extended) and try again.

Comment: Wow, I just tried to import an MP3 audio file and it didn't work -- I don't recall having experience that before! I've reset warnings, but am not getting any error messages: the MP3 file just isn't adding to iTunes.

Comment: Can you check whether the target directory is writable by your user? And I don't think it's an encoding issue at all.

Comment: Permissions are fine, but on glancing through the iTunes preferences it turns out that there was no location set for the iTunes Library! I've set this, and now everything is working again. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: I have the same problem with the video but I was wondering if there was a size limit. Because my vidéo is in 1080p and it's only 5min long bug it's heavy (2,5Gb).

Comment: No idea, although that would surprise me. My problem was caused by there being no iTunes Library location set in iTunes preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no iTunes Library location set in iTunes preferences.

Answer (score -2):

After you add the files, a tab will show up under Movies called "home videos." Your mp4s are there.

Comment: OP specifically said that the movies aren't showing up there...